# Why superclass constructor Building() is invoked when I say new House("x ")?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have the following code but I don't get why when I run this it prints `"b"` before printing `"h hn x"`. Why does `"b"` get printed at all since I am not calling the superclass `Building` at all when I execute `House()`.

```
class Building {
    Building() {
        System.out.print("b ");
    }

    Building(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.println("bn " + name);
    }
}

public class House extends Building {
    House() {
        System.out.println("h ");
    }

    House(String name) {
        this();
        System.out.println("hn " + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new House("x ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In inheritance it is necessary to initialize all the fields present in super-class first, because those fields are get used in subclasses, for this before construction of your subclass super class constructor get called to initialize all the field present in your super class.

Super class constructor called when you construct subclass instance. In your code you are creating `new House("x ");` Instance of `House`.

It calls `House` parametrized constructor `House(String name)` at this time your super class implicit constructor get called.

Answer (score 5):

The zero-arg constructor of a superclass is implicitly called by the constructor of its subclass, automatically.

More generally, for

```
class B extends A
```

The constructor

```
public B()
{
    //Your code
}
```

Actually looks like

```
public B()
{
    super(); //Call the superclass constructor
    //Your code
}
```

You can override this behavior by making an *explicit* call to some other superclass constructor. Note that if the implicit call to the constructor cannot be made (like if your no-arg constructor doesn't exist), then you will see an error.

Answer (score 3):

The superclass constructor is always called whenever a subclass is being constructed. If the superclass constructor does not require any arguments, as is the case here, this call can be made implicitly.

If you were to introduce an argument in the constructor for Building, you'd get an error in House as it will require you to explicitly call the new superclass constructor.

Answer (score 3):

### Official resource:

From the Oracle javase tutoriel:

> With `super()`, the superclass no-argument constructor is called. With
>   `super(parameter list)`, the superclass constructor with a matching
>   parameter list is called. Note: If a constructor does not explicitly
>   invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically
>   inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If
>   the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get
>   a compile-time error. `Object` does have such a constructor, so if
>   `Object` is the only superclass, there is no problem.
>
> If a subclass constructor invokes a constructor of its superclass,
>   either explicitly or implicitly, you might think that there will be a
>   whole chain of constructors called, all the way back to the
>   constructor of `Object`. In fact, this is the case. It is called
>   *constructor chaining*, and you need to be aware of it when there is a
>   long line of class descent.

### Additional resource:

The section *Constructor Chaining* From the SCJP 6 book explains clearly what you are looking for with in a simple manner, it provides also a little more informations about this process:

> We know that constructors are invoked at runtime when you say new on
>   some class type as follows: `Horse h = new Horse();` But what really
>   happens when you say `new Horse()` ? (Assume `Horse extends Animal` and
>   `Animal extends Object`.)
>
> 1. `Horse` constructor is invoked. Every constructor invokes the constructor of its superclass with an (implicit) call to `super()`,
>      unless the constructor invokes an overloaded constructor of the same
>      class (more on that in a minute).
> 2. `Animal` constructor is invoked (`Animal` is the superclass of `Horse`).
> 3. `Object` constructor is invoked (`Object` is the ultimate superclass of all classes, so class `Animal` extends `Object` even though you don't
>      actually type `"extends Object"` into the `Animal` class declaration. It's
>      implicit.) At this point we're on the top of the stack.
> 4. `Object` instance variables are given their explicit values. By explicit values, we mean values that are assigned at the time the
>      variables are declared, like `"int x = 27"`, where `"27"` is the explicit
>      value (as opposed to the default value) of the instance variable.
> 5. `Object` constructor completes.
> 6. `Animal` instance variables are given their explicit values (if any).
> 7. `Animal` constructor completes.
> 8. `Horse` instance variables are given their explicit values (if any).
> 9. `Horse` constructor completes.

### Analogy with your example:

So when you said `new House("x ")`, here is what happens:

1. The `House(String name)` invokes `House()` as specified by the keyword `this()`.
2. The `House()` constructor  implicitly calls `super()` which invoks the construcotr `Building()`.
3. The `Building()` constructor implicitly calls `super()` which is the `Object` constructor.
4. The `Object` constructor completes
5. The `Building()` constructor will complete and print `"b "`
6. The `House()` constructor will complete and print `"h"`
7. The `House(String name)` constructor will complete and print `"hn x "`.
8. The result is `"b h hn x "`

**NB:**  `Building(String name)` would be invoked if you added an explicit call from `House()` to `super("someString")`, in that case the result will be: `"b bn someString h hn x "`

Answer (score 1):

If you step through program the call stack shows what's happing:

(you need to follow the call stack from bottom to top):

`House(Building).<init>() line: 3`

`House.<init>() line: 2`
`House.<init>(String) line: 7`
`House.main(String[]) line: 12`

1. First Main is called
2. Then in the House(name) constructor this() is called
3. This calls the House() constructor (because no argument is provided)
4. Now comes the interesting part: because the    Default constructor is called and House is derived from Building, it is required to construct the Building first which by specification is the default constructor of the parent class Building.